# In Squarespace, when I add jquery CDN code, the Adirondack logo disappears. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I need to have a jquery press widget on my site using the Adirondack template, and I added jquery cdn code to the header via code injection. However, this makes the logo not show up. I also tried adding the cdn jquery code to the footer too and there was no difference. (Though the cdn jquery makes my widget work.) The logo shows up fine without the jquery cdn code. Does anyone know how to avoid this conflict?

Here is the site I'm working on: 
https://shara-karasic-4b4j.squarespace.com/

Here is the jquery cdn I'm using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: First, I think you'll want to get rid of the extra opening script tag `<script type="text/javascript">`. From there, inserting the first script tag in the header code injection area should work.

Comment: That makes the logo show up, but then the widget stops working if I remove the <script type="text/javascript"> part. How can I have the logo and widget both show up?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The reason this did not work is that this portion of the jquery code was conflicting and causing the logo to disappear. I removed it and it worked!

```
     //logo top
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("h1, #social-icons").hide();
   $(window).scroll(function(){
     var height = $(window).scrollTop(); //pour calculer la position de la barre verticale

     if( height >= 200) { 
       $("h1, #social-icons").fadeIn(300);
     }

     else{ //sinon
       $("h1, #social-icons").fadeOut(300);
     }
   }); //fin de window scroll

 }); //fin de doc ready
```